# What master page is used for SharePoint Site Settings pages?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, master-pages

I'm wanting to edit the master page that is used for the Site Settings pages in a SharePoint site. I've changed the main master page but it doesn't alter the Site Settings page. What page do I need to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Magus said that it uses Application.Master, It is not a best / recommended practice to edit any of the SharePoint page directly, Refer to [this](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2007/01/08/one-master-to-rule-them-all-two-actually.aspx) article for how to achieve what you want.

Comment: The link for "this article" http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2007/01/08/one-master-to-rule-them-all-two-actually.aspx was broken (when I tried it a few times over several days). Here is the Internet Archive version, https://web.archive.org/web/20080228055341/http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2007/01/08/one-master-to-rule-them-all-two-actually.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's using the application.master Master page.